# How to structure an application (and its user interface) such that extraneous and/or malformed data can be handled?

Tags: data, error-handling, error-detection

I recently applied for a position as a software developer. As a part of the recruitment process, I was given an assignment that involves reading data from a file.

The thing is that the example file contains extraneous data *on purpose*. For example, there's a CSV file in which decimal numbers are sometimes written using decimal points and sometimes using commas (which are also the delimiters of the CSV columns). The reason, according to the problem statement, is that some numbers were manually updated by a non-technical European user.

The data itself is not hard to read. I've identified some patterns in the erroneous data, and there is a wealth of techniques (like Regex) that I could use to read the files *on a case-by-case basis*, but these techniques are usually scripty, hacky, and hard-coded.

With that being said, I wonder if this recruiter wanted me to develop an application that can handle extraneous data in general, without hard-coding the logic for these particular cases.

To accomplish this I've come up with a few reasonably creative solutions, none of which I am fully satisfied with:

- Including controls such that the user can create a chain of filters and manipulations for the data that is being read. I don't think this is a good solution because it is too technical for the average user (a store manager), who just wants to upload the data and be done with it. This could work if a programmer is the one who uploads the data, but then the solution becomes too expensive.
- Saving everything, except the erroneus rows, and then showing the user the ones that are malformed, allowing him to correct them before continuing.

I also wonder if the recruiter was actually asking something really simple, which I misunderstood, leading me to over-think the problem, but then, the problem statement says that my solution has to be developed using S.O.L.I.D. principles.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for handling stuff that can't be handled is to feed back to the user and allow them to correct.

Generally with processing dirty input like this you would return a list of errored lines with the error message for each and allow the user to fix and reprocess the file.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter could comment to explain what they think is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Ask more questions. I cannot speak for your recruiter, but a good one would appreciate that a candidate discusses the task.
- Coding style, such as using SOLID principles, is not very relevant to the questions about the specification you asked. The only thing which seems related is that you probably want to have a list of format handlers using inherited classes so you can try them uniformly.

Comment: I don't understand your point about coding style.

Comment: You are not sure how your application should behave. But how it behave does not depend if it is developed with SOLID principles of not, and generaly does not affect it, it can be either way